# Pass a JavaScript object to Apex controller in lightning

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning, object, parameters

Is it possible to pass a JavaScript object to Apex controller in lightning?

Here is what I tried:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void changeProgram(Object info) {
    update new zced__Training_Program__c(
      Id = info.Id
    );
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Variable does not exist: Id

[image]

I believe I am getting this because `Object` in Apex and object in JavaScript are different things.

So, I found that there is such a thing called JavaScript Map and there are a lot of examples how to pass it from client-side controller to server-side. And I am feeling it can easily substitute the JavaScript object, but still I would like to know for sure whether or not it is possible.

I am only interested in the Apex part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apex is *strongly typed*, which means that it has to know in advance what type of data it's dealing with. In this specific case, you could have just passed in an Id:

```
public static void changeProgram(Id recordId) {
```

In the more general sense, you can pass in a Map, which is as close as you get to a JavaScript object:

```
public static void changeProgram(Map<String, Object> info) {
  update new zced__Training_Program__c(
    Id = (Id)info.get('Id')
  );
}
```

Or, perhaps more preferentally, you can pass in an entire sObject:

```
public static void changeProgram(zced__Training_Program__c record) {
  update record;
}
```

But that requires altering the JavaScript parameter to match; the object has to have the correct type:

```
action.setParams({ record: { sobjectType: 'zced__Training_Program__c', Id: 'somerecordid' }});
```

Comment: Oh. Yeah, I knew the last approach. Actually it works even without setting the `sobjectType`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a JSON String of your object and pass to apex Controller. The input param in apex method can be a string which you can deserialize.

```
var action = component.get("c.changeProgram");

action.setParams({  param1: JSON.stringify(object)});// setting the parameter to apex class method
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void changeProgram(String param1) {
   // deserialize your string

}
```

Comment: Could you, please, provide an example of actually accessing the sent data in Apex?

Answer (score 2):

To build on Anurag A's answer, you can create a JSON String of your object in your JS controller using JSON.stringify() and pass it as a String variable to your Apex controller. Then you can use Apex's JSONParser to parse the key-value pairs into a Apex Map (which is different from a JS map because reasons) like so:

```
var jsObject= { key1 : value1 , key2 : value2};
var packagedString = JSON.stringify(jsObject);
```

...and then pass them to your Apex controller using the standard code (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm).

In your Apex method, you can then unpackage the map using the following code:

```
Map<String, String> unpackedMap = new Map<String, String>();
String tempKey, tempValue;

//Unpack the packaged JSON string. Use the JSONParser class to read the JSON 
//string, iterate over and extract each Key 
//and associated value and send it to our Apex map.
JSONParser parsedMap = JSON.createParser(jsonStringFromJavascript);
while(parsedMap.nextToken() != null) {
    if(parsedMap.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
        tempKey = parsedMap.getText();
        parsedMap.nextToken();
        tempValue = parsedMap.getText();
        unpackedMap.put(tempKey, tempValue);
    }
}
//Will return the value associated with key1
system.debug(unpackedMap.get('key1'));
```

This has the benefit of allowing you to stuff any data into the JSON string, not just data that is associated with an SObject.